Can I perform work myself on my HVAC ductwork in Nevada?
A section of the duct work in my house has collapsed (suspiciously right after the ducts were cleaned). Does the repair have to be done by an HVAC certified repair person or can I do it myself?

You need to be HVAC certified to mess with refrigerant.
No one cares how you fix ductwork

HVAC ducts are considered passive element, no risk of flooding or burning your home down thus no permit needed to fix it.
This would be a DIY job
